# I can't install python3.10-minimal on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in container

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I have a container with ubuntu 22.04 lts and when I need to install a package or program that requires pyhton3.x-minimal it throws a permissions denied error, I am also root. It is something strange but I have not been able to solve it.

This is program installa

```
root@c0f46f619a6c:/var/www/html#apt-get install systemd
```

And the installation throws the following message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dmsetup gir1.2-glib-2.0 libcryptsetup12 libdevmapper1.02.1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libip4tc2 libjson-c5 libkmod2 libmpdec3 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
  networkd-dispatcher python3 python3-dbus python3-gi python3-minimal python3.10 python3.10-minimal systemd-timesyncd
Suggested packages:
  iw | wireless-tools python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv python-dbus-doc python3.10-venv python3.10-doc binutils binfmt-support systemd-container libfido2-1 libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0
  libtss2-mu0 libtss2-rc0 policykit-1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dmsetup gir1.2-glib-2.0 libcryptsetup12 libdevmapper1.02.1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libip4tc2 libjson-c5 libkmod2 libmpdec3 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
  networkd-dispatcher python3 python3-dbus python3-gi python3-minimal python3.10 python3.10-minimal systemd systemd-timesyncd
0 upgraded, 21 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 41.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpython3.10-minimal amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1 [810 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3.10-minimal amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1 [2263 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-minimal amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04 [24.3 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libmpdec3 amd64 2.5.1-2build2 [86.8 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpython3.10-stdlib amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1 [1831 kB]
          
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.10-minimal:amd64.
(Reading database ... 19257 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3.10-minimal.
Preparing to unpack .../python3.10-minimal_3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.10-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1) ...
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-310.pyc.140322885704192'dpkg: error processing package python3.10-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.10-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.10-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried changing some execute and write permissions but the problem persists

Comment: Python3.10-minimal should be a normal part of your installation.  Is the __future... file rw-r-r owned by root?

Comment: this is what the ls command throws me -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 /usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-310.pyc.140322885704192

Comment: None of the pyc files in my __pycache__ directory have a large number at the end, and the 0 length on your --fut... file is wrong, mine is 4131.  Maybe since it's in cache, just delete it, but no idea what that might do -- reinstall?

Comment: @ubfan1 python is not currently included into the ubuntu docker image from dockerhub. That docker image has very minimal tools out of the box, for the sake of efficiency

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and the solution was to change the way I was running docker in my computer as apparently there is a bug in how docker got installed in Ubuntu 22.04 using snap that generates this issue.

More info in this thread: https://forums.docker.com/t/bug-on-apt-install-permission-denied/100196

Exact steps I followed to fix it are this ones: https://forums.docker.com/t/bug-on-apt-install-permission-denied/100196/9

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the following sequence of actions helped:

1. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
2. `sudo systemctl restart docker`
3. `sudo systemctl restart docker.socket docker.service`
4. `docker rm -f <container id> // remove all containers which can cause your problem`
5. Retry docker container building

Comment: This worked for me. I did not perform step 5, and it still worked in my case. Thanks